# NullPointerException with SelectableDataModel and ViewScope with PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, jquery-ui-selectable

I am facing a problem with SelectableDataModel and ViewScope. Below is what I implemented:
Facelet:

```
<p:dataTable id="countries"
        value="#{userPreferencesBean.countryDataModel}"
        var="country" emptyMessage="No Country found."
        selection="#{userPreferencesBean.selectedCountries}"
        styleClass="table-no-select-all" dynamic="true" rowKey="#{country.id}">
        ......
</p:dataTable>
```

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = UserPreferencesBean.MANAGEDBEAN_NAME)
@ViewScoped
public class UserPreferencesBean implements Serializable {

  //All Variable Declarations goes here
  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
      List<Country> coountries = Getting countries from DB
      setCountryDataModel(new CountryDataModel(coountries));
  }
  public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
      //Nothing here
  }
  ...
}
```

CountryDataModel:

```
@ManagedBean(name = CountryDataModel.MANAGEDBEAN_NAME)
@ViewScoped
public class CountryDataModel extends ListDataModel<Country> implements SelectableDataModel<Country>,
    Serializable {
    public CountryDataModel() {
    }

    public CountryDataModel(List<Country> countries) {
        super(countries);
    }

    @Override
    public Interface getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Country> countries = (List<Country>)getWrappedData();
        for (Country singleCountry : countries) {
            if (isEqualWithRowKey(singleCountry.getId(), rowKey))
                return singleCountry;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isEqualWithRowKey(Short countryId, String rowKey) {
        Short rowKeyId = Short.parseShort(rowKey);
        if (countryId.equals(rowKeyId))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Country singleCountry) {
        return singleCountry.getId();
    }
}
```

Now what is happening is that first time, datatable is getting loaded correctly. But when I am clicking on a particular row, I am getting NPE. Log is below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:936)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:40)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:415)
```

Comment: In which line is the error exactly being thrown?

Comment: public Interface getRowData(String rowKey)  that's the method

Comment: do you mean that line 936 is public Interface getRowData(String rowKey) ?

Comment: Yes the at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:936)

Comment: When you get data from DB and set to `List<Country> coountries`, make sure the `id` of each Country is not null.